# Dynamics AX Add Products Filters without Retail Add On

Tags: axapta, x++, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

I need to enable the filters section of the Add Products form (RetailAddProducts) when called from a Purchase Order Form.  This feature is only native to Retail Catalogs as I understand it but I need to bypass this.  Is this possible?  If so how would I go about making this adjustment?  I am still a fresh developer when it comes to Dynamics.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to override it by modifying the checkAndAddHierarchy method and adding some extra logic.  Thanks for the pointers though.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely have to change the ConfigurationKey of various elements to expose the function. This may include menu items, tables and fields of the feature.

Comment: Any clue what configuration key to change them to?  All attempts so far have been futile.